# How to get Report Page list based on Report ID using power bi client in C#?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, powerbi-embedded

Need to get page list of a Report based on ReportId from powerbi in my web api project. Couldn't find any option in power bi client object for fetching page info in C# web api. Tried using HttpClient then but still getting forbidden error with below code-

```
        var accessToken = await GetAccessToken(authMode);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("reports/" + reportId);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var pageList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<PageInfo>>();
            return pageList;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<PageInfo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way you can get all the pages of a `report` based on `reportId` using C# Web API.

Please check:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Get-List-Of-Report-Pages-via-C-Rest-API/m-p/376293

However, you can use [powerbi-client (JS SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/) to get all the pages of a `report`.

Please refer below code:

```js
// reportContainer: HTML div element in which report is being embedded
// config: Report embed configuration object
const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
const pages = await report.getPages();

// pages is an array which contains all the pages available for the given report.
console.log(pages);
```

Please refer here:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/report.report#getPages__
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-pages

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is now possible:

```
var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId);
var pages = await pbiClient.Reports.GetPagesInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, ReportId);
```

(using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api v4.18.0)